# antlr4 works fine on a .g4 grammar file, but gradle generateGrammarSources fails on the same file with TokenStreamException: unexpected char: '-'/"

Tags: exception, gradle, antlr, antlr4

I am experimenting with the antlr plugin for gradle and trying to generate some source files for my grammar. Using the ANTLR Mega tutorial as a guide. When I run the antlr4 tool manually on my grammar through the terminal, it succeeds and generates *.java, *.tokens & *.interp files. I am trying to generate these files through the gradle plugin and getting an error 
"> ANTLR Panic: TokenStreamException: unexpected char: '-'".

Do I expect gradle generateGrammarSources to have the equivalent functionality of running the antlr command directly on my grammar?

The grammar file is based on one of Antlr's example: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/arithmetic/arithmetic.g4

```
user-MBP:antlr user$ antlr4 
ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 4.7.2

user-MBP:main-project user$ ls  src/main/antlr/
arithmetic.g4

user-MBP:antlr user$ antlr4 arithmetic.g4 
user-MBP:antlr user$ ls
arithmetic.g4               arithmetic.tokens           arithmeticLexer.interp      arithmeticLexer.tokens      arithmeticParser.java
arithmetic.interp           arithmeticBaseListener.java arithmeticLexer.java        arithmeticListener.java
```

Gradle code to do the same:

```
apply plugin: 'antlr'

...

dependencies {
...
    compile group: 'org.antlr', name: 'antlr4-runtime', version: '4.7.1'
...
}

// as the .g4 grammar file is already present in src/main/antlr, not  // explicitly specifying any package directory
```

Running the gradle command

```
user-MBP:main-project user$ gradle generateGrammarSource --stacktrace

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ANTLR Panic: TokenStreamException: unexpected char: '-'
        at antlr.Utils.error(Utils.java:34)
        at antlr.Tool.fatalError(Tool.java:445)
        at antlr.Tool.doEverything(Tool.java:280)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

I expect the above gradle command to successfully run and generate equivalent source files in the build/ directory, but it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing the antlr tool that generates the grammar in my gradle dependencies. ANTLR has two components: 
 - the tool used to generate the lexer and parser from the grammar (antlr dependency)
 - the runtime required to run the source files generated (antlr4-runtime)

Adding the following line in my gradle dependencies solved the issue.

```
    dependencies {
        ...
        antlr "org.antlr:antlr4:4.7.1"
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. In my case I've imported `antlr` dependency as `implementation` but it was wrong.

**WRONG:** `implementation("org.antlr:antlr4:4.11.1")`

**CORRECT** `antlr("org.antlr:antlr4:4.11.1")`

`antlr-runtime` is used for runtime use of generated code. You don't need it if, you only want to generate the source code itself.

Here is my entire `build.gradle.kts` for reference:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.21"
    antlr
    application
}

group = "com.me.myproject"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    antlr("org.antlr:antlr4:4.11.1")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}
```